# Android 11 - System.loadLibrary for native C++ library takes 60+ seconds, works perfectly fast on Android 10 and below

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x, android-11

In our game application for Android which is based on the game engine cocos2d-x, with most of the code being written in C++, we have a very strange and critical issue since Android 11:

When the native library gets loaded in `onLoadNativeLibraries` it now suddenly takes 60+ seconds. Before Android 11, it all worked fine and it loaded in 0.2-3 seconds. Now when you start the game, you have a 60+ seconds gray screen.

We already figured out that `JNI_OnLoad` gets called directly after the 60 second stall is over.

Here's the code of the `onLoadNativeLibraries`
function:

```
protected void onLoadNativeLibraries()
{
    try
    {
        ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        Bundle bundle = ai.metaData;
        String libName = bundle.getString("android.app.lib_name");
        System.loadLibrary(libName); // line of 60 seconds stall
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

We already tried time profiling, but without any success. It just hows that it's spending a lot of time on that function. Also pausing via the debugging doesn't lead to any further clues. The native debugger doesn't show anything on the C++ side of the code.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening or what we could try to figure it out? Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Do you explictly set `android:extractNativeLibs` in your manifest? Which Android Gradle Plugin version do you build with? Is the load time the same in release mode as in debug mode?

Comment: @Michael No, we don't do that - should we set it to something? We use gradle-5.6.4.
 It's also very long in release mode, yes.

Comment: I meant the Android Gradle Plugin. The one you specify as a dependency in your project-level `build.gradle` file. It ought to have a version starting with 3 or 4.

Comment: Also, does this always happen? Or only the first time after installing a new version of the app?

Comment: @Michael Sorry, sure makes sense. There we have `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'`
Yes, it happes always. 100% of the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

It's a bug in Android 11 fixed by google but not deployed yet.

Meanwhile, if you don't care about calling *static* and *thread_local* variables destructors in your lib when program is exiting/library is unloaded, pass the flag `-fno-c++-static-destructors` to the compiler. (see long answer for a more granular solution using clang annotations)

I used this flag on my project (not cocos2d) with no issue and lib is loading even faster than before.

**Long Answer:**

Unfortunately this is a performance regression introduced in android 11 (R) by the Google team. The issue is being tracked by google [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168043760).

To summarize, when `System.loadLibrary()` is called, the system registers a destructor for each of the C++ global variables contained in the loaded library, using [__cxa_atexit()](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_1.3.0/gLSB/gLSB/baselib---cxa-atexit.html)

Since Android 11 (R), the implementation of this function in android has [changed](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/bionic/+/1231458/):

> - In Q, __cxa_atexit uses a linked list of chunks, and calls mprotect
>   twice on the single chunk to be modified.
> - In R, __cxa_atexit calls
>   mprotect twice on a single contiguous array of handlers. Each array
>   entry is 2 pointers.

This change regressed the performance drastically when they are many C++ global variables which seems to be the case in cocos2d *so* libraries.

Google has already implemented a fix https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/bionic/+/1464716 but
as stated in the issue:

> this won't be in Android 11 until the March QPR at the earliest, and
> since this isn't a security issue it won't be mandatory for OEMs to
> actually take that patch.

Google Team suggests also some [workarounds](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168043760#comment14) at the app level by removing or skipping the destructors on global variables:

> - For a particular global variable, the [[clang::no_destroy]] attribute skips the destructor call.
> - Pass -fno-c++-static-destructors to the compiler to skip the destructors for all static variables. This flag also skips destructors
>   for thread_local variables. If there are thread_local variables with
>   important destructors, those can be annotated with
>   [[clang::always_destroy]] to override the compiler flag.
> - Pass -Wexit-time-destructors to the compiler to make it warn on every instance of an exit-time destructor, to highlight where the
>   __cxa_atexit registrations are coming from.

Comment: `-fno-c++-static-destructors` seems to work perfectly. Thanks a lot. We already tried to debug this with all kinds of tricks for 4 days straight to no avail. Thank you :)